# A way around passing the address of an integer literal to the function?

Tags: c, pointers

So I have a header file that defines all the constants/register addresses used in the project and I have a function that takes in the pointer to the data, but you can't pass in a reference of the integer literal since it's an value. Is there a better way around it?

```
#define REG_A   (uint8_t) 0x3

void transmit_data(uint8_t *p) {
 //...
}

int main(void) {
  uint8_t arr[2] = {0xab, 0xca};
  
  transmit_data(arr);
  transmit_data(&REG_A); // won't work since it's an value but that's what i'm trying to achieve

}
```

Comment: How does `transmit_data` know how much data to transmit? Also, is `transmit_data(&REG_A)` supposed to transmit a byte whose value is 0x3, or is it supposed to transmit the data *in* register A?

Comment: How is `transmit_data` supposed to know how much data to transmit? `transmit_data(arr);` suggests it transmits the two bytes of `arr`, but `transmit_data(&REG_A);` would only have one byte available.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a compound literal to construct an object on the fly:

```
transmit_data(& (uint8_t) {REG_A});
```

The construct **(** *type* **) {** *value* **}** creates an object with type *type* and value *value*.

Because an array will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element in this circumstance, you can also write it without the explicit `&` operator:

```
transmit_data((uint8_t []) {REG_A});
```

Comment: i see. so the main idea behind compound literals is to create an unnamed object of specified type and value?

Comment: @Pokloha: Yes. Outside of a function, it has static storage duration. Inside a function, it has automatic storage duration associated with its enclosing block.

Comment: right. is there a way to dynamically pass the size of the array or determine inside the function than explicitly hardcoding it?

Comment: @Pokloha: Not once the array has been converted to a pointer. One can use a macro in the calling routine that provides both the start of the array and its size, such as `#define Kludge(x) (x), sizeof (x) / sizeof *(x)`, but this is not good code, is prone to error, and should be avoided.

Comment: yeah but for that I'd need to explicitly define an array in the caller code since the size can't be determined via pointer like you said. does the idea of passing the size of the array in the last index of the compound literal sound bad?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use macros?

In the header:

```
extern uint8_t REG_A;
```

In one of the source files:

```
uint8_t REG_A = 0x3;
```

Then you can pass the address to your function.